# Firebase - Saving JSON online

Tags: json, database, firebase

I'm totally new to Firebase and was wondering if there was a way to copy the data from this source: `https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest`

Using this header;

`'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'cab79c7b-52e9-4e4b-94fc-b0f32da14799'` (free API key)

To a firebase database every **5 minutes**.

This would mean that I'd need a way to have the database refresh the data it stores from the aforementioned source so that from a standalone app I could download this data for use.

I need this to be updated every five minutes as the data from the source is also updated regularly, and having a five-minute interval between each fetch would allow me to fit between the 333 times my key is allowed to visit the source per day.

I'm trying to get this working as a workaround to daily restrictions on the source, so that if more people than 333 use the app (most certain) per day, they don't run into restrictions.

After directly contacting the data source, they have assured me that this is a supported method of use for their product, which can be found under `Implementing a Caching Strategy` at [this link](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Best-Practices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase there are the Firebase-Cloud-Functions you can perfom a `fetch()` request (they are written in Node.js, you can also use an Ajax request). These Functions can have a Time-trigger which you can set in the configs. You can check them out [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?authuser=0)

There you can set the Request Headers to your key and save the result in your Cloud-Firestore.

Comment: This looks great, never knew this was possible with Firebase (as I said I’m new to this) so I’m pretty impressed. I’ll get back to you on this incase I need assistance, thanks

Comment: How do I access the space in which I can write this code? Just incase there's any confusion, I'd like this to be executed entirely by Firebase, so I don't need a remote trigger.

Comment: You can simply write a normal Node.js-Function and then use the [firebase-cli](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/) to login your project and push the Firebase-function. You can also, while selecting your project with `firebase init` select the Cloud-Functions option to get a predefined workspace on your machine, where you can write and manage your functioins

Comment: These functions are serverless, so they 'exist' only whilst they are executet. And the time trigger is managed by Firebase, so that you don't need your own trigger.

Comment: Can you point us to the documentation for the Firebase config settings for the Time-triggers?

Comment: [This can be achieved using the cloud scheduler ](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart)

Comment: Ah - so this is essentially a cron job trigger and is a separate and unrelated product to the Firebase product. Good to know.